# Include js( javascript page ) in freemarker template pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, freemarker

I am working on RIOT CMS having Front End as FreeMarker templates.tried to include trial.js into one of the .ftl pages but this change is not reflecting in  project's front-end page. Please correct it if any one of you have tried this befre?This is how I used===>

```
<@template.extend> 
  <@template.block name="trial"><#include "/trial.js"> </@template.trial>    
</@template.extend>
```

//trial.js need to be included in my .ftl page

I have been using jsp before and free marker is completely new for me.                       As a starter,I am trying to change my jsp pages to free marker(.ftl) pages. My aim is to include js & css in .ftl like we do in JSP .

Comment: If you just write some static text into that `template.block`, does it show? If it doesn't, your problem has nothing to do with includes. Also, a failing inclusion throws exception in FreeMarker, it doesn't just silently does nothing (unless, Alfresco has some weird template exception handler).

Comment: yes ddekany,the same happenin.static text is not showing but no errors in Mozilla Firefox Firebug console.                                                        one more thing ddekany,I am not using Alfresco Template Model.I am playing around Free Marker Template for my riot cms project

Comment: I have been using jsp before and free marker is completely new.As a starter,I am trying to change my jsp pages to free marker(.ftl) pages .want to include js & css in .ftl like I did in JSP .

Comment: Maybe the problem is that Riot CMS (not FreeMarker!) caches the *output* of template blocks. Ideally it should invalidate the cached item if the related template was modified (at least in "development mode"... if they have such thing as production VS development mode), but I don't know Riot.